# RoundRectBorder's delayed blur paints over new forms?

Tags: codenameone

1, I have a very heavy form with a lot of components using `RoundRectBorder`.

2, I have own `callSerially` jobs going on in the background

3, I show another form and end my own background jobs

-> it seems the loop continues on to finally render the `RoundRectBorder` blur effect probably still in the `pendingSerialCalls` list, but at this point the form is already switched and therefore its painting on top the new form, messing it up.

Could this be a codename one bug or some mishandling on my side?

[image: Result of profiling]

Comment: It could very well be a Codename One bug but I need to understand what you did in the code? `RoundRectBorder` reneders as part of a component so if the form changed the component (hence the border) shouldn't have access to the graphics anymore.
I would suggest checking the EDT violation tool in the simulator and making sure there are no violations.

Comment: There are no EDT violations shown (I'm debugging on the highest level), I just see in the profiler that the blur is rendered on a new form without any roundrectborders - when the messing up is happening. (I added a screenshot of the profiler.)

Comment: I also got aware of this:  [link](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2045)

Comment: The delayed creation of the border is fine. The problem is the access to the new form. The border invokes `component.repaint()` (in line 471). This shouldn't matter if the component isn't showing as the repaint operation goes up the hierarchy to the parent form and shouldn't go through unless the form is the current form

Comment: So, any idea what could cause this? It's definitely weird as an old form paints over a new one, and it only paints the components with RoundRectBorder. Everything else works fine. And the only activity I can see in the profiler at the time when this is happening is the shown in the picture above (the new form which has no RoundRectBorder at all).

Comment: Is it possible you have an operation that blocks or violates the EDT? It might delay a `hideNotify` event and allow an errant repaint call to go through...